# Como funcionam decoradores em Python?

Tags: python, decorator-pattern, sintaxe

O @Elizeu Santos perguntou no grupo de Python em português do facebook o seguinte:

> "Fala galera, to estudando python e uma coisa que não estou entendendo
>   são os decorators. Dei de cara com eles fazendo o tuto de flask, podem
>   me esclarecer?"

(O facebook não é legal para responder perguntas que incluam português e código misturado nos comentários - aqui é muito melhor formatado pra isso - então trouxe a pergunta pra cá, para colar a resposta que eu escrevi pra ele)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Uma função em Python é um objeto como qualquer outro - quando fazemos `def func(): ...`, o nome `func` fica associado ao corpo da função que é definido depois do comando `def`.

Um *decorator* é uma função (ou outro objeto chamável) que recebe uma função como parâmetro e retorna uma função. Essa nova função que é retornada pelo *decorator* é que fica associada ao nome da função original.

Ou seja, suponha um *decorator* `deco`, se for usado com a sintaxe de 
`@` faz exatamente o mesmo que isso aqui:

```
def func():
   # faz coisas
func = deco(func)
```

Esse trecho de código é o mesmo que:

```
@deco
def func():
   #faz coisas
```

Nos dois casos, depois desse trecho de código, o nome `func` fica associado ao objeto que foi retornado pela chamada a função `deco`. Em geral esse objeto é uma função que chama a função `func` original, mas faz alguma coisa antes ou depois de chamá-la.

Por exemplo, um decorador que simplesmente registra quantas vezes as funções que ele decora foram chamadas, numa variável global `contador` pode ser declarado assim:

```
contador = 0

def contar_acessos(funcao_decorada):
    # não sabemos quantos parâmetros existirão na chamada
    # da função funcao_decorada, então recebemos *args e **kw
    def nova_func(*args, **kw):
         global contador
         contador += 1
         # e chamamos a função original, com os parâmetros recebidos:
         return funcao_decorada(*args, **kw)
    # retornamos a função "nova_func" - que só faz 
    # incrementar o contador e  retornar o valor da chamada à função original
    return nova_func

# agora vamos usar o decorador:
@contar_acessos
def soma(a, b):
    return a + b
```

---

E quando colamos esse código no interpretador interativo e chamamos `soma` algumas vezes, temos:

```
>>> contador
0
>>> soma(2,2)
4
>>> soma(3,2)
5
>>> soma("a", "b")
'ab'
>>> contador
3
```

---

Então, nesse caso simples, tudo o que é feito é aumentar o valor da variável contador antes de chamar a mesma função que foi decorada (e que dentro da função `nova_funcao` está com o nome de `funcao_decorada` já que ela é passada como parâmetro para a função de fora, a `contar_acessos`).

Mas você pode sofisticar a coisa - pode-se criar uma função que guarde o valor de retorno da função decorada num dicionário, por exemplo, daí você faz um cache simples (memoize). Pode-se simplesmente registrar a função decorada numa lista de "funções que fazem algo", e retornar ela mesma, sem criar uma nova função decoradora. Acredito que é isso que o Flask faz - anota a sua função decorada como uma função que responde a um endereço na URL.

Comment: Gostei da iniciativa. Por mais que eu saiba o que são os decorators em Python, eu sempre tenho que treinar e reler, para não ficar confuso