# Para que serve a declaração [HttpGet]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, python

Em um determinado método do meu `Controller` criado no `Asp Net MVC`, eu aprendi que eu podia colocar a declaração `[HttpGet]`.

Em outros casos, como nos meus models, percebi que pode ser colocado também `[Length(10)]` e ainda outras coisas.

Estou familiarizado um pouco com isso no `Python` (de declarar coisas "em cima" do método).

Por exemplo:

```
 @app.route('/')
 def home(response):
     return template(response, 'meu_template.html')
```

Em `Python` isso é chamado de decorator.

E em C#? Essa declaração feita em cima do método serve para o mesmo propósito que os decorators do `Python`?

Qual é o nome dessa Sintaxe?

Referências:

- [Como funcionam decoradores em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23628/como-funcionam-decoradores-em-python)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119024/como-criar-um-custom-attribute

Comment: @GabrielKatakura acho que isso responde à pergunta, viu

Comment: Isso em C# tem o nome de [atributo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx).

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho tempo no momento para formular uma resposta, e não gosto de dar respostas simplesmente com links.

Comment: -1 porque a pergunta é duplicada? Duplicada não é útil? Não faz referência para outra pergunta? Ok, né

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wallace, o [`[HttpGet]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpgetattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) e o [`[Length]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) são [`Attributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx), que são à forma de implementar o `Decorator Pattern` no `.NET`.

Eles são uteis quando você deseja associar alguma informação adicional a sua classe, campo, propriedade, etc.

Se desejar implementar o seu proprio Attribute, basta criar uma classe que herde direta ou indiretamente de `System.Attribute`, como nos exemples abaixo.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ClassInfoAttribute : System.Attribute 
{    
   public string Namespace { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public ClassInfoAttribute()
   {
   }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class FieldInfoAttribute : System.Attribute 
{    
   public string DataType { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public FieldInfoAttribute()
   {
   }
}
```

para utilizalos, basta atricionar um atributo sobre a sua classe, campo, propriedade com o nome do Atributo (sem o Attribute).

```
[ClassInfo(Namespace = "Meu Namespace", Name = "Minha Classe")]
public class MinhaClasse
{    
   [FieldInfo(DataType = "Texto", Name = "Minha Propriedade")]
   public string MinhaPropriedade { get; set; }

   [FieldInfo(DataType = "Texto", Name = "Meu Campo")]
   public string meuCampo;

   public MinhaClasse()
   {
   }
}
```

se precisar recuperar o attributo, vai precisar usar um pouco de `System.Reflection`

```
var classe = new MinhaClasse();
var tipo = classe.GetType();
var campo = tipo.GetField("meuCampo");
var propriedade = tipo.GetProperty("MinhaPropriedade");
var classIndo = (ClassInfoAttribute)tipo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ClassInfoAttribute), false);
var fieldInfo = (FieldInfoAttribute)campo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldInfoAttribute), false);
var propertyInfo = (FieldInfoAttribute)propriedade.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldInfoAttribute), false);
```

Já que mencionou o `ASP.NET MVC`, um atributo que talvez seja bom você conhecer são os `Action Filter`, para tal basta implementar à interface `IActionFilter` e herdar de `ActionFilterAttribute`.

```
public class MeuFiltroAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) { ... }
    void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) { ... }
    void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) { ... }
    void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) { ... }  
}

[MeuFiltro]
public class MinhaController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Então, você implementa um `atributo` e não uma função como se faz em `Python`?

Comment: Na verdade isto é um decorador, mas nada tema ver com o https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern. É possível implementar o Decorator Pattern com ele, mas é preciso esforço adicional. Nos exemplos mostrador tem apenas um metadado, nada mais. Veja mais na pergunta original a esta que foi marcada como duplicada.