# Quais as diferenças entre o Decoradores e Atributos?

Tags: terminologia, atributos, decorator-pattern

Eu fiz uma pergunta recentemente sobre o [uso de atributos que foi introduzido no PHP 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/487642/como-funcionam-os-atributos-do-php-8). Atributos para mim acaba não soando como novidade, porque lembro de ter visto algo parecido quando trabalhei com [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/).

Lembro até que a sintaxe não é muito diferente do PHP:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class SampleClass
{
    // Objects of this type can be serialized.
}
```

Porém surgiu uma certa dúvida quando me lembro que vi algo parecido no Python. Sei que em Python é chamado de [decorators](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23628/como-funcionam-decoradores-em-python).

```py
@app.route('/')
 def home(response):
     return template(response, 'meu_template.html')
```

Lembro-me de ter feito [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126726/para-que-serve-a-declara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-httpget) referente à sintaxe do C#, mas fico na dúvida se não fiz confusão entre Decorator e Attributes hoje em dia.

As minhas dúvidas são:

- Os Decoradores e os Atributos são/fazem a mesma coisas? Os decoradores do Python por exemplo têm a mesma finalidade que as do C# e PHP?
- Caso não sejam a mesma coisa, quais são as diferenças entre eles?
- Existem outras linguagens além do Python que usa o termo "decoradores"? Isso é um termo padrão da linguagem ou é familiar na programação?
- Os termos "decoradores" e "atributos" podem ter outros nomes dependendo da linguagem de programação usada?

Comment: Pelo que percebo, tem uma diferença pratica importante, alguns apenas adicionam uma informação extra ao ponto (classe, método, função, etc) onde são definidos, portanto, por si só, não fazem nada, precisam de algum meio de reflexão pra serem usados. Enquanto outros, são sempre executados quando definidos, não precisam de nada além deles mesmo (não que não possa ter), por isso são (pelo menos os que conheço) uma função. Agora, qual termo é uilizado pra cada um, não sei dizer, nem como funciona em cada linguagem, no TypeScript, sei que é do 2° modo, provavelmente, por necessidade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certos termos podem ser usados em contextos um pouco diferentes e podem ter grandes ou pequenas diferenças de interpretação.

Sobre PHP eu respondi [O que são atributos no PHP? (Annotations/Attributes/Decorators)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/484081/101).

Geralmente o atributo (de verdade, não [a confusão que as pessoas fazem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)) é um mecanismo usado, frequentemente, para atingir o objetivo do chamado Decorator Pattern. Outros mecanismos podem ser usados, até porque algumas linguagens não possuem formas próprias.

Uma forma de decorar algo é encapsular uma função em outra, então em vez de chamar diretamente a função que deseja, chama outra que "prepara o terreno" e eventualmente finaliza a função principal.

Quando se usa atributo geralmente precisa de algum mecanismo que automatize isso e faz algo extra, geralmente através de reflexão, em tempo de execução ou em tempo de compilação. Fica uma sintaxe mais limpa e pode ser menos confuso, quando a pessoa sabe o que faz.

Uma linguagem pode chamar o atributo de outros nomes, como anotação (Java) ou até decorador, como visto acima.

A forma exata de funcionar pode ser diferente em cada linguagem, mas a essência é a mesma. Meu entendimento é que Python, C# e PHP possuem os mesmos mecanismos, ainda que possam ter pequenas diferenças de funcionamento.

Não lembro de todos detalhes de todas linguagens para falar sobre os termos delas, lembro de ver o uso de decorador só em Python.

Nem sei os detalhes de várias linguagens. Eu sei que em Python o decorador é efetivamente uma função. Em C# é uma classe e Java também, ainda que mais difícil de fazer, e parece que PHP copiou igual. Pode ser que as maiores diferenças estejam nos métodos de reflexão para acessar os atributos e mudar o comportamento ou configurar como uma função deve ser executada. Acho que seria até amplo falar disso porque seriam várias linguagens e muitos detalhes.

Curiosamente em C# eu vejo muito as pessoas usando atributos de forma muito descritiva, mas ele pode ser muito mais que isso, a classe que cria um atributo pode ter virtualmente qualquer código. É verdade que na maioria das vezes não é necessário ter, mas quando pode ser útil as pessoas esquecem ou não sabem que pode.

Eu gostaria que existissem decoradores só em tempo de compilação, porque a maioria só é usado nesse caso, e se a linguagem tem reflexão em tempo de compilação (C# agora tem), quase não precisa de outra forma. C# tem proposta para ter esses decoradores que não vão para o executável.

Eu acho curioso quando uma linguagem adota um mecanismo bem tarde, e assim ela pode fazer melhor porque aprendeu com os erros dos pioneiros, e ela comete os mesmos erros, pior ainda quando outras linguagens estão consertando. Aí eu falo que a linguagem não evolui bem, as pessoas acham que eu sou *hater* de linguagem, eu lido com fatos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).