# Programar uma função em Python para executar sempre na ultima sexta-feira do mês

Tags: python, python-2.7

O código abaixo demonstra um exemplo de como programar, mas é um pouco limitado a minutos, horas e dias. Eu preciso de um que inclua também o mês e o dia específico, que no meu caso é a sexta-feira. Consegui um código que obtém a data da ultima sexta-feira do mês corrente, mas não soube como integrar usando o **schedule**.

```
import time
import schedule
import calendar
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, FR

def last_friday_of_month(month=None, year=None):
    month = month or date.today().month
    year = year or date.today().year
    return date(year, month, 1) + relativedelta(
        day=calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1],
        weekday=FR(-1)
    )

def job(string):
    print(string)

schedule.every().thursday.at("11:49").do(job, "I'm working...")

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então - a biblioteca schedule não suporta isso. 
Por isso, a forma mais simples vai ser você simplesmente agendar a tarefa para todas as sextas-feiras, e colocarum código de filtro na entrada da função: se a data atual não for a última sexta-feira do mês, então retorne sem executar.

Claro que a primeira vista isso parece implicar em colar código de cálculo de datas e etc dentro da sua tarfea, que pode não ter nada a ver com isso, e ainda repetir esse código em várias tarefas em que você queira fazer algo parecido.

Aí é que entram os "decoradores" - decoradores são modificadores de função que tem uma sintaxe específica no Python: basicamente eles podem "ensanduichar" o código da sua função original e rodar, opcionalmente, algum código antes ou depois - o código do decorador fica separado da sua função principal, e você usa apenas uma linha para modificar o comportamento da sua função. Eu explico bem o seu uso nessa resposta: [Como funcionam decoradores em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23628/como-funcionam-decoradores-em-python)

Então, você pode criar um decorador assim:

```
import datetime
from functool import wraps

def only_on_last_friday(func):
   @wraps(func)
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       today = datetime.date.today()
       if today ==  last_friday_of_month(year=today.year, month=today.month):
           return func(*args, **kwargs)
       return None
   return wrapper
```

Pronto - em combinação com sua função de encontrar a última sexta do mês, ela só vai executar a chamada a função final se for chamada na última sexta.

Você tanto pode aplicar o decorador à sua função final, como simplesmente decorar no momento de chamar o scheduler - dessa forma a função continua normal para o restante do seu código, e só o scheduler recebe a função modificada para rodar só na data escolhida:

```
@only_on_last_friday
def job(string):
    print(string)

schedule.every().friday.at("11:49").do(job, "I'm working...")
```

ou:

```
def job(string):
    print(string)

schedule.every().friday.at("11:49").do(only_on_last_friday(job), "I'm working...")
```

(Não sei se você está usando o `dateutils` para outras coisas, mas se não estiver, tenho uma versão do last_friday usando só o datetime padrão:)

```
from datetime import date, timedelta 

def last_friday(year, month):
    minus_one_day = timedelta(days = 1)
    next_month = date(year, month, 27) + timedelta(days=7)
    result = date(next_month.year, next_month.month, 1)
    while True:
        result -= minus_one_day
        if result.weekday() == 4:  # Friday
            return result
```

Aproveitando o ensejo, se você está usando esse código é importante para você ter algo no lugar que assegure que o programa esteja rodando, mesmo após vários dias ligado. Há um projeto em Python muito legal para isso chamado `supervisor` - que pode garantir isso com bem pouco trabalho - vale a pena olhar:

http://supervisord.org/

Comment: Ok, doutor. Irei fazer alguns testes. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!