# Converter os argumentos da função para string

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Como converter os argumentos da função para string? Sem ter que digitar todos os argumentos**

Tentei resolver da seguinte forma:

```
def teste(a, b, c, d, e='F9', f=1):
    for key, value in locals().items():
        key = str(value)
    message = ' '.join(['inicio', a, c, d, e, f, b])
    return message

t = teste('C6', 1, 2000, 'E4')
print(t)
```

Porém key no dicionário não é uma variável da função `teste()`, então o valor de value convertido para string não é passado para a variável.

A solução encontrada foi de converter para string todas as variáveis, digitando o nome de cada variável:

```
def teste(a, b, c, d, e='F9', f=1):
    message = ' '.join(str(x) for x in ['inicio', a, c, d, e, f, b])
    return message


t = teste('C6', 1, 2000, 'E4')
print(t)
```

Mas como realizar isso sem precisar digitar cada variável, como por exemplo com a utilização de `locals()`?

Comment: [Relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23628/75104)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você não tem necessidade de distinguir entre os argumentos, você pode usar o recurso do `*` na declaração dos parâmetros de uma função - isso indica que a função indica um número variável de argumentos anônimos que já é passado para a função como uma tupla - e aí, é simples converter todos:

```
def teste(*args):
   return ' '.join(str(arg) for arg in args)

teste(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Se alguns dos seus parâmetros precisam de nome, você pode usar `**` para receber os parâmetros como um dicionário -

```
def teste(*args, **kw):
   return ' '.join(str(arg) for arg in (args + tuple(kw.values()) ) )

teste(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, alo=7, mundo=8)
```

Se você precisa ter valores padrão nos parâmetros, como está no seu exemplo, aí não tem jeito, ou você vai ter que digitar os nomes por extenso, ou usar uma combinação de técnicas de introspecção como o que está tentando fazer para iterar sobre os nomes das variáveis. Não vejo como isso poderia ser uma boa prática - um nome de variável é importante e faz algo independente no seu programa, ou, se você fosse ter várias variáveis que vai tratar do mesmo jeito, é melhor colocar esses valores numa lista ou dicionário.

Se você precisar fazer isso em várias funções, seria bem errado ter que replicar essa lógica em todas - o ideal aí é usar um decorador que transforma os tipos dos parâmetros quando a função é chamada - e você já fornece tudo transformado em string para sua função.

O uso de um decorador inclusive permite que seus parâmetros tenham nome na função final (e o decorador consome argumentos genéricos usando "*" e "**"). Só não dá mesmo conta de argumentos padrão - esses não são passados para o decorador.

```
def tudo_string(func):
    def decorador(*args, **kwargs):
         args = [str(arg) for arg in args]
         kwargs = {key: str(value) for key, value in kwargs.items()}
         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorador

@tudo_string
def teste(a, b, c, d, e='F9', f=1):
    # Todos os parâmetros serão recebidos já convertidos em string aqui,
    # exceto o valor padrão de f que é dado "dentro" do decorador.
    ...
```