# Para que serve o "@" no python?

Tags: python, flask

Várias vezes eu me deparei com trechos de código python que utilizavam o "@" como no flask:

```py
import flask
App = flask.Flask(__name__)
@App.route("/")
```

Por que nao simplesmente `App.route`?

Comment: Isso responde sua pergunta ? [Como funcionam decoradores em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23628/como-funcionam-decoradores-em-python)

Answer (score 2):

O "@" como prefixo de uma expressão que está uma linha acima de uma declaração de função ou de classe é um "decorador" (decorator em inglês) . O que são e o funcionamento de decoradores está explicado na pergunta que foi marcada como sugestão de que esta seria uma duplicata: [Como funcionam decoradores em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23628/como-funcionam-decoradores-em-python)

`@` como decorador:

```
@modificar_funcao
def minha_funcao():
    ...
```

No entanto, reabri a questão, por que há um outro uso de `@`que não é abordado naquela pergunta: ele pode ser usado com um operador que usa dois operandos (assim como `+ - * /`) - e nesse contexto, ele indica uma " multiplicação de matrizes". A operação de multiplicação de matrizes não está definida em nenhum tipo que acompanha uma instação padrão de Python, por isso é pouco conhecida - mas o "numpy", principal biblioteca com operações de matrizes em Python usa o "@" com esse sentido. Além disso, qualquer classe criada nos seus programa pode definir uma operação com o "@" como operador se implementar o método `__matmul__`.

`@` como operador de multiplicação de matrizes:

```
In [7]: import numpy as np                                                                                  

In [8]: A = np.ones((2,2))                                                                                  

In [9]: B = np.ones((2,1))                                                                                  

In [12]: A[0,0] = 3                                                                                         

In [13]: B[0, 0] = 5                                                                                        

In [14]: A                                                                                                  
Out[14]: 
array([[3., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])

In [15]: B                                                                                                  
Out[15]: 
array([[5.],
       [1.]])

In [16]: A @ B                                                                                              
Out[16]: 
array([[16.],
       [ 6.]])
```