# Encapsulamento de funções

Tags: python, funções

Abaixo está um exemplo de uso de função passada como parâmetro para outra função:

```
def gera_nums():
    lista = []
    for c in range(0, randint(1, 15)):
        lista.append(randint(0, 100))
    return lista


def extrai_maior(array):
    print(f'Os números passados foram: {array}')
    print(f'Foram passados {len(array)} números como parâmetro!')
    print(f'O maior número passado foi o {max(array)}.')


extrai_maior(gera_nums())
```

Basicamente a primeira função gera um número **x** aleatório (até 14 números) de números aleatórios (entre 0 e 99) e retorna uma lista. Essa função é passada como parâmetro para a função `extrai_maior` que analisa a lista e passa algumas informações.

Levando em consideração que a primeira só será utilizada com a segunda, é pertinente encapsular a primeira dentro da segunda, certo? Como ficaria esse código? Não estou conseguindo aplicar.

PS: O uso de lambda neste caso é inviável pois não daria pra transformar a primeira função em função inline, né?

Answer (score 6):

Não, esse não é um exemplo de uso de função passada como parâmetro para outra função.

Quando faz...

```
extrai_maior(gera_nums())
```

... na verdade está apenas passando **o resultado da função** `gera_nums()` como parâmetro para a função `extrai_maior()` pois quando coloca os `()` a frente do nome da função você a está executando.

Para que a função `gera_nums()` seja passada como parâmetro a função `extrai_maior` deve ser modificada para receber uma função e chamar dentro de seu corpo:

```
from random import randint

# Simplificando a função gera_nums utilizando list comprehension
gera_nums = lambda: [randint(0, 100) for c in range(0, randint(1, 15))]

#Função preparada para receber outra função pelo parâmetro f
def extrai_maior(f):
    array = f() # aqui chama o parâmetro como uma função
    print(f'Os números passados foram: {array}')
    print(f'Foram passados {len(array)} números como parâmetro!')
    print(f'O maior número passado foi o {max(array)}.')

#Agora gera_nums é passada como parâmetro
extrai_maior(gera_nums)
```

Outra possibilidade é criar um decorator, veja [Como funcionam decoradores em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23628/como-funcionam-decoradores-em-python):

```
from random import randint


gera_nums = lambda: [randint(0, 100) for c in range(0, randint(1, 15))]

def extrai_maior(f):
    #array = f() #se chamar f() aqui você cria um closure e o decorator sempre retornará o mesmo valor
    #cria um decorator
    def deco():
      array = f() # aqui chama o parâmetro como uma função
      print(f'Os números passados foram: {array}')
      print(f'Foram passados {len(array)} números como parâmetro!')
      print(f'O maior número passado foi o {max(array)}.')
    return deco #retorna o decorator

#aplica o decorator
gera_nums = extrai_maior(gera_nums)

#Poderia ser usado o açúcar sintático @ mas a função gera_nums() teria que ser movida e modificada
#@extrai_maior
#def gera_nums(): 
#return (lambda: [randint(0, 100) for c in range(0, randint(1, 15))])()

#evoca a função decorada
gera_nums()
```

Comment: Aula! Porém não sei se entendi bem a parte do decorator, não estou devidamente iniciado nesse conceito, apesar de já ter lido sobre. Pode me explicar de maneira sintética? Vou pesquisar conteúdo em paralelo para trocarmos melhor. Obrigado!

Comment: @dev.curi Sobre decorators, pode começar por aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23628/112052

Answer (score 3):

Quando você fala "encapsular função" creio que você esteja falando de *funções aninhadas*. Para fazer isso, basta você colocar a sua função `gera_nums()` dentro de `extrai_maior()` e definir a chamada função dentro da segunda função.

Veja abaixo como ficaria o código:

```
def extrai_maior():

    def gera_nums():
        lista = []

        for c in range(0, randint(1, 15)):
            lista.append(randint(0, 100))
        return lista

    array = gera_nums()

    print(f'Os números passados foram: {array}')
    print(f'Foram passados {len(array)} números como parâmetro!')
    print(f'O maior número passado foi o {max(array)}.')

extrai_maior()
```

Se me permite dizer, não acho que seja certo nesse caso você deixar a função `gera_nums` dentro de `extrai_maior`. Primeiro porque não faria sentido o nome da função nesse código. Imagine... seria para extrair maior de que ? Não faz sentido, já que o array já é gerado dentro da função.

Segundo, você não poderia obter a lista para ser usada em outros lugares, já que a função `gera_nums` só existe no escopo da função `extrai_maior`. Então se você quisesse utilizar o array numa função `extrai_menor` por exemplo, você deveria criar uma outra função `gera_nums`, criando linhas desnecessárias e poluindo seu código.

No seu caso, acho que o código que você fez foi a melhor opção.

---

Agora respondendo a sua outra pergunta, realmente ficaria inviável criar todo o código usando somente `lambda`, mas é possível criar a função `gera_nums` em uma única linha. Veja como ficaria:

```
gera_nums = lambda: [randint(0, 100) for c in range(0, randint(1, 5))]
```

Nesse código acima, eu precisei utilizar além do `lambda` um [list comprehensions](https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/list-comprehensions-no-python).