# Qual é a diferença na hora do retorno destas duas formas?

Tags: python, funções

```
def seja_educado(funcao):
    def sendo():
        print('Foi um prazer!')
        funcao()
        print('Tenha um ótimo dia!')
    return sendo
```

---

```
def seja_educado(funcao):
    def sendo():
        print('Foi um prazer!')
        funcao()
        print('Tenha um ótimo dia!')
    return sendo()
```

Qual a diferença da primeira função para a segunda, quero dizer qual a diferença faz se eu chamar a função sendo ou sendo() ??

Comment: Podemos assumir que ambos serão utilizados como decoradores, dada a tag "decorator-pattern" que adicionou na pergunta?

Comment: É que estou estudando sobre Decoradores em Python e ai em um dos vídeos  o professor explicou só que não ficou muito claro sobre a chamada dessa função desses dois modos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta fazer um simples [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878). Supondo que exista uma função qualquer chamada `spam`, poderemos analisar ambas as implementações.

```
def spam():
    """ Uma função qualquer """
    ...
```

Na **primeira forma** temos:

```
def seja_educado(funcao):
    def sendo():
        print('Foi um prazer!')
        funcao()
        print('Tenha um ótimo dia!')
    return sendo
```

Isto é, definimos uma função `seja_educado` que recebe como parâmetro uma função; definimos localmente uma nova função `sendo` que executará a função de entrada com as mensagens antes e depois; a função `seja_educado` retorna a função `sendo`. Ou seja, o retorno da função `seja_educado` é uma função. Assim, podemos testá-la:

```
>>> egg = seja_educado(spam)
>>> type(egg)
<function seja_educado.<locals>.sendo at 0x...>
```

Assim, sendo `egg` uma função, podemos chamá-la, `egg()`, e isso executará a função `sendo`, que exibirá a mensagem "*Foi um prazer!*", executará a função `spam`, que é a que passamos por parâmetro ao definir `egg` e finalmente exibirá a mensagem "*Tenha um ótimo dia!*"

Já na **segunda forma** temos:

```
def seja_educado(funcao):
    def sendo():
        print('Foi um prazer!')
        funcao()
        print('Tenha um ótimo dia!')
    return sendo()
```

A implementação é basicamente a mesma do que a primeira forma, apenas diferenciando no tipo de retorno. Enquanto a primeira retorna a função `sendo` esta forma retornará o **retorno da função `sendo`**. Porém, a função local `sendo` não possui retorno explícito e, portanto, será `None`. Assim, o retorno da função `seja_educado` sempre será `None`.

Fazendo o mesmo que fizemos na primeira forma, teremos:

```
>>> egg = seja_educado(spam)
Foi um prazer!
Tenha um ótimo dia!
>>> type(egg)
None
```

Ou seja, a função `spam` já será executada no momento que `seja_educado` for chamada e o retorno em `egg` sempre será `None`.

No âmbito de decoradores, o primeiro faz mais sentido, pois o retorno é uma função - o segundo **pode** fazer sentido, em situações muito específicas, pois ao utilizar um decorador em uma função você a sobrescreverá com o retorno deste decorador. Ou seja, fazer:

```
@seja_educado
def spam():
    ...
```

É o mesmo que fazer:

```
def spam():
    ...

spam = seja_educado(spam)
```

Na segunda forma, como o retorno sempre é `None`, ao utilizar como decorador você estaria definindo `spam` como `None`, o que não faz sentido na grande maioria dos casos.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pela ajuda !

Answer (score 2):

`return sendo()` faz o seguinte: o Python chama a função `sendo`, roda seu código, e o valor que ela retornar fica no lugar da expressão `sendo()`. No caso, como  a função `sendo` não tem um comando `return`, ela retorna `None`  e esse valor é retornado pela função `seja_educado`.

Essa forma não serve para ser um decorador - a função já executa a função interior, e essa execução acontece uma única vez.

Já em  `return sendo`, a própria função é retornada. Pense que é como se fosse uma variável que tem a função dentro (é isso que nomes de função são em Python) - então, o valor de retorno da função `seja_educado` é ele mesmo uma função  - que vai poder ser chamado, sempre que tiver o `()` depois dele - essa forma serve como um decorador -

Quando se usa a sintaxe de decoradores em Python  - o nome de uma função com o `@` antes da declaração de uma função, o que acontece é que a função que é o decorador vai ser chamada com a função declarada abaixo   - e o que essa função retornar vai ficar *no lugar* da função que está decorada. Então se um decorador não devolve uma função, ou outra coisa que pode ser chamada com o "()", o comportamento pode ser bem estranho.

Para entender melhor, sugiro dar uma olhada nessa questão que explica bem decoradores:

[Como funcionam decoradores em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23628/como-funcionam-decoradores-em-python)

Comment: A sim agora ficou mais claro, muito obrigado !